# How do I input filepath by sys.stdin in python?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I wrote a simple py by using sys.stdin

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
  print "hello" + line
```

While I need to import filepath as import to execute in my function.
When I use sys.stdin and run it into command line.

```
    ~$ python metrics.py
    /Users/glange/graphs/Building768.0.json
    ctrl+D
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:  
    '/Users/glange/graphs/Building768.0.json\n'
```

I enter the filepath then ctrl+D. It cannot be run. It seems When I finished the filepath I need enter a new line to ctrl+D. And the path becomes \n in the end.
How can I fix that?

Comment: You might prefer [fileinput](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html) module

Comment: The only code you post would not produce that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use .rstrip() to remove the new line character

```
print "hello" + line.rstrip()
```